# How to encrypt/decrypt a single file ecryptfs-style without mounting?

Tags: ecryptfs

How can one encrypt/decrypt a single file ecryptfs-style without mounting the whole filesystem? I am basically looking for a `gpg -e`/`gpg -d` analogue that produces output that can be understood by ecryptfs and used in userspace.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Generating a file that can be mounted by `ecryptfs` without having to install it?

Comment: Exactly, see [this older question](http://superuser.com/questions/133300/). That aside, I am also looking into using ecryptfs for data archival and for that it would be nice to have a simple portable data extractor that is still going to work in 20 years, not some kernel module that will be incompatible with whatever kernels version we are using then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a utility to do that, I wrote one myself. Only does extraction to stdout at the moment and doesn't support encryption. It also only supports password protected files and doesn't support public keys. This thing hasn't been tested much, so there will be bugs, but it's at least a starting point in documenting the file format somewhat (which is flawed in quite a few ways):

- https://github.com/pecryptfs/pecryptfs

Comment: Was able to use this tool with `docker run --rm -it -v /path/to/my/private-files:/private -v /path/to/pecrytpfs-clone:/app python:3.6 bash` and then running 'cd /app && pip install . && pip install pycrypto' 

Thanks for writing it.

Answer (score 1):

pgp / gpg, tar & bash have been around for a few decades now, odds are they will still be available in a few more. For making backups for long-term archiving I'd use them

I'd go with gpg encrypting individual files (easily batched in a bash script), or even tar archive files (optionally compressed, but gpg can do that too).

Then later for seeing what's in the archives, doing a `gpg -d file.gpg | tar -tv` would list it's contents without actually decrypting everything to a file, and extracting only a file or two is possible too.